# Unexpected results for android xml layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm beginner in android development and often have received the strange results. Below is markup where I expect to see red and green sequential rectangles. But really I see only green area:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/first_constrain"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/second_constrain"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/first_constrain"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:background="#00FF00">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Please explain what is wrong in my code.

Comment: **FrameLayout** arranges your elements one above the other, As a result you can see the last element on the screen. Simple solution, just to replace **FrameLayout** to **LinearLayout**

Answer (score 0):

That is because of the parent `FrameLayout` - FrameLayout arranges elements (children) on top of each other.

You need to change the parent layout to other layouts e.g. `Linear` or `ConstraintLayout` Layouts - something like this.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/first_constrain"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/second_constrain"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/first_constrain"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:background="#00FF00"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I need to use FrameLayout. I have expected that app:layout_constraint... ones guarantee the positions of the red and grren parts.

Comment: Docs say FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen **to display a single item**. Generally, FrameLayout **should be used to hold a single child view**. You can [read more about here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout)